# Count children from hierarchy path

Tags: sql, postgresql, hierarchical-data, materialized-path-pattern

I have a table like this:

| id | name | path |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | /1 |
| 2 | Mark | /2 |
| 3 | Kevin | /1/3 |
| 4 | Sarah | /1/3/4 |
| 5 | Andy | /2/5 |
| ... | ... | ... |

So, I can say that Sarah is Kevin's child which is John's child.

I would like to have this:

| id | name | path | number of children |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | John | /1 | 2 |
| 2 | Mark | /2 | 1 |
| 3 | Kevin | /1/3 | 1 |
| 4 | Sarah | /1/3/4 | 0 |
| 5 | Andy | /2/5 | 0 |
| ... | ... | ... | ... |

TASK NUMBER 2:
Let's say that I have this table too

| id | income | user_id |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1 | 200 | 1 |
| 2 | 120 | 1 |
| 3 | 340 | 2 |
| 4 | 500 | 3 |
| 5 | 600 | 5 |
| 6 | 80 | 5 |

I can say that John has a Total income of 320$, but if I also want to count John's children, it is 820$ (because id =3 is John's child). So, I would also like a query where I can count all the hierarchical incomes.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name you're right. I'm sorry, my mistake

Comment: You will do better while *normalizing your table and store only `parent_id` and not a full `path`.

Comment: @MarmiteBomber Really? Why? Because if I put all the path to me it's easier because every user has the "history" of all the tree but if I only put the parent_id then I think it is a little bit harder to understand the grandchildren and great grandchildren and so on

Comment: You will learn why if you one day wakes up and you will see this   paths `/**2**/3/6` . So, who is the father of `3`? It can be both `2` and `1`. This is called *normalization* - please check [Database_normalization](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Database_normalization)

Comment: Basically meaning store every piece of data only in **one** place. Even in you small sample there are **two** rows (3,4) where is defined `1` is parent of `3`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber OK, I understand this but if I find some path like /**2**/ it means there is an error because only id must be shown in the path.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/242777/discussion-between-fabio-manniti-and-marmite-bomber).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do:

```
select
  t.*,
  (select count(*) from t c where c.path like t.path || '/%') as c_count,
  i.income + (
    select coalesce(sum(i.income), 0) from t c join i on i.user_id = c.id
     where c.path like t.path || '/%'
  ) as c_income
from t
left join (
  select user_id, sum(income) as income from i group by user_id
) i on i.user_id = t.id
```

Result:

```
 id  name   path    c_count  c_income 
 --- ------ ------- -------- -------- 
 1   John   /1      2        820      
 2   Mark   /2      1        1020     
 3   Kevin  /1/3    1        500      
 4   Sarah  /1/3/4  0        null     
 5   Andy   /2/5    0        680
```

See example at [DB Fiddle](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/gc5q66GR19mEDaA2xxY7VA/1).

Comment: The count reported is actually the count of all dependent rows (not the *number of child*), but this is the best what can be done without parsing the path to get the `parent_id`

Comment: @MarmiteBomber but I do want to know ALL dependent rows. Not only the first child

Comment: Well this is fine, but than you should not name the column `number of children` but e.g. `number of dependent nodes` - to avoid confusion @FabioManniti